# How to solve equations with undetermined parameter and initial conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

```
yyyy = 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "4", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)(
r) == -0.0015074999999999997` (-((\[Psi](
     r) (18.04` r^4 \[Omega]^2 + 1990.0497512437814`))/r^4) + (
  1990.0497512437819` Derivative[1][\[Psi]](r))/r^3 - (
  1990.0497512437814` \[Psi]^\[Prime]\[Prime](r))/r^2 + (
  1326.6998341625213` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)(r))/r);
a1 = \[Psi][0.09`] == 0;
a2 = Derivative[1][\[Psi]][0.09`] == 0;
a3 = (\[Psi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0.09`] == 1;
a4 = 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0.09`] == 0;
```

w is a parameter,I would like to solve the above initial value problem for '[Psi] (0.35)'; I truncate the domain of the problem to 0.09=< r<=0.35,What is the best way (in terms of performance) to automate getting the solution to the initial value problem in Mathematica?

Comment: Please look at [this post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) then repost your code in a more legible way that does not contain Box expressions.

Comment: Voting to close as too simple, too localized, and too ill-formed to be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `NDSolve` after giving `ω` a numeric value.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{eqns, f},
  eqns = 
         {Derivative[4][ψ][r] == 
             -0.0015074999999999997*
               ((-ψ[r])*((18.04*r^4*ω^2 + 
                         1990.0497512437814)/r^4) + 
                  1990.0497512437819*
                    (Derivative[1][ψ][r]/r^3) - 
                  1990.0497512437814*
                    (Derivative[2][ψ][r]/r^2) + 
                  1326.6998341625213*
                    (Derivative[3][ψ][r]/r)), 
    ψ[0.09] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][ψ][0.09] == 0, 
    Derivative[2][ψ][0.09] == 1, 
    Derivative[3][ψ][0.09] == 0}; 
  f = NDSolve[eqns, ψ, 
     {r, 0.09, 0.35}][[1, 1, -1]]; 
  Plot[f[r], {r, 0.09, 0.35}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 0.065},
   AxesLabel -> {"r", "ψ[r]"},
   Epilog -> {
     Text[StringForm["ψ[0.35] = ``", f[0.35]], 
      {0.35, f[0.35]}, {1.25, 0}],
     Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
     Point[{0.35, f[0.35]}]}]], 
   {{ω, 500}, 0, 10^3, 10, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

EDIT: Added plot of \[Psi][0.35]

```
eqns = {
   Derivative[4][\[Psi]][r] == -0.0015074999999999997*((-\[Psi][r])*
        ((18.04*r^4*\[Omega]^2 + 1990.0497512437814)/r^4) +
       1990.0497512437819*(Derivative[1][\[Psi]][r]/r^3) -
       1990.0497512437814*(Derivative[2][\[Psi]][r]/r^2) +
       1326.6998341625213*(Derivative[3][\[Psi]][r]/r)),
   \[Psi][0.09] == 0,
   Derivative[1][\[Psi]][0.09] == 0,
   Derivative[2][\[Psi]][0.09] == 1,
   Derivative[3][\[Psi]][0.09] == 0};

psi35[\[Omega]_?NumericQ] :=
 \[Psi][0.35] /. 
  NDSolve[eqns, \[Psi], {r, 0.09, 0.35}]

Plot[psi35[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 0, 500},
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "\[Psi][0.35]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are great.Can you help me to get the Plot[\[Psi][0.35],\[Omega]] ?

Comment: @1112131424 - see edit above.

Comment: I learned a lot from your program.Thank you very much,

Comment: Would you mind taking a look about  the following problem?@Bob Hanlon

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Changed your code. Bob Hanlon

```
eqns[ω_] = {Derivative[4][ψ][
     r] == (-(((1990.0497512437814 - 2.885572139303483*^8*r^2 - 
              4.1044776119403*^10*r^3 + 
              r^4*(18.040000000000003 + 4510.*r)*ω^2)*ψ[
             r])/r^4) - ((-1990.0497512437814 - 
            1.1641532182693481*^-10*r + 2.885572139303482*^8*r^2 + 
            4.1044776119403*^10*r^3)*Derivative[1][ψ][r])/
        r^3 - ((1990.0497512437819 + 328358.2089552239*r - 
            4.5771144278606975*^8*r^2 - 1.0385572139303485*^11*r^3)*
          Derivative[2][ψ][r])/
        r^2 - ((-1326.6998341625213 - 1.9900497512437818*^6*r - 
            7.462686567164181*^8*r^2 - 8.291873963515756*^10*r^3)*
          Derivative[3][ψ][r])/r)/(-663.3499170812605 - 
       497512.43781094544*r - 1.2437810945273636*^8*r^2 - 
       1.0364842454394695*^10*r^3),
   ψ[0.09] == 0,
   Derivative[1][ψ][0.09] == 0,
   Derivative[2][ψ][0.09] == 1,
   Derivative[3][ψ][0.09] == 0};

f[ω_?NumericQ] := ψ[0.35] /. 
  NDSolve[eqns[ω], ψ, {r, 0.09, 0.35}][[1]]

f[200]

(*  0.0188641  *)
```

Comment: After program running,getting the NDSolve::nlnum.......and InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {0.35} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."

Comment: I edited your "answer" with correct code.